# While Loop not Executing in C

Tags: c

I am unable to get this program to print out the lines of symbols with a tab. I included a picture of how it should be printing. Currently it's working except that there is no indentation. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

The idea is to display even numbered lines with indents (‘\t’) and the odd ones without indent:

Example of correct output

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num_lines;
    printf("Enter a number of lines, greater than or equal to 7, to print :  ");
    scanf("%d", &num_lines);

    if (num_lines < 7) {
        while ( num_lines < 7 ) {
            printf("Enter the number of lines to print\nMust be greater than or equal to 7 :  ");
            scanf("%d", &num_lines);
        }
    }

    char symbol;
    printf("Choose a symbol/character to be displayed */&/+/0/x :  ");
    scanf(" %c", &symbol);

    int num_symbols;
    printf("Enter the number of symbols to print per line :  ");
    scanf("%d", &num_symbols);

    if (num_symbols < 7 || num_symbols > 27) {
        num_symbols = 19;
    }

    while (num_lines > 0) {
        int n = num_symbols;
        int nl = 1;
        int nll = nl / 2;

        while (nl <= num_lines) {
            if ( (nl % 2) == 0) {
                while (nll > 0) {
                    printf("\t");
                    --nll;
                }
                while (n > 0) {
                    printf("%c", symbol);
                    --n;
                }
            }
            else {
                while (n > 0) {
                    printf("%c", symbol);
                    --n;
                }
            }
            ++nl;
        }
        printf("\n");
        --num_lines;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

^_^

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num_lines;

    do{
        printf("Enter the number of lines to print\nMust be greater than or equal to 7 :  ");
        scanf("%d", &num_lines);
    }while(num_lines < 7);


    char symbol;
    printf("Choose a symbol/character to be displayed */&/+/0/x :  ");
    scanf(" %c", &symbol);

    int num_symbols;
    printf("Enter the number of symbols to print per line :  ");
    scanf("%d", &num_symbols);

    if (num_symbols < 7 || num_symbols > 27) {
        num_symbols = 19;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= num_lines; ++i) {

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            for (int m = 0; m < i / 2; ++m) {
                printf("\t");
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < num_symbols; ++j) {
            printf("%c", symbol);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to print your desired pattern :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num_lines,i,j;
    printf("Enter a number of lines, greater than or equal to 7, to print :  ");
    scanf("%d", &num_lines);

    while ( num_lines < 7 ) {
        printf("Enter the number of lines to print\nMust be greater than or equal to 7 :  ");
        scanf("%d", &num_lines);
    }

    char symbol ;
    printf("Choose a symbol/character to be displayed */&/+/0/x :  ");
    scanf(" %c", &symbol);

    int num_symbols;
    printf("Enter the number of symbols to print per line :  ");
    scanf("%d", &num_symbols);

    if (num_symbols < 7 || num_symbols > 27) {
        num_symbols = 19;
    }
    i = 1;
    while (i <= num_lines) {
        if(i%2 == 0){
            j = i/2;
            while(j != 0){
                printf("\t");
                j--;
            }
        }
        j = 0;
        while(j < num_symbols){
            printf("%c",symbol);
            j++;
       }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Here is the output:]

Answer (score 0):

In your loop there are problems in the way you declare your variables and put your conditions.
Try to think step by step:
1. Am I on on a pair or impair line?
2. If yes I put \t
3. Print x times my number
4. Do the same until you've done enough lines

```
if (num_symbols < 7 || num_symbols > 27) {
    }
    int which_line = 1;
    while (num_lines > 0) {
        if (which_line % 2 == 0) { //STEP 1
         for (int tmp_line = which_line - 1; tmp_line >= 1 ; tmp_line--) { //STEP2
         printf("\t");
            }
        }
        for (int tmp_symbols = num_symbols; tmp_symbols >= 1 ; tmp_symbols--) { //STEP 3
           printf("%c", symbol); 
        }
        printf("\n");
        which_line++; //STEP 4
        --num_lines;
    }
```